# How to map matching property values into same object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I'm mapping matching Objects into one where the ID property values match.
So far the reduce and map works fine for the `ID` and `Fet` properties.

But now I want to map the **Name** property to each new mapped object. I did try the following but this creates a new Object separate to the others with the `Name` values.

How can I map matching property values to an object?

https://jsfiddle.net/brianVarley/zs8xadht/

This is what I tried in order to get the `Name` mapping:

```
const arr = [{ ID:12, Fet: "Donuts", Name: "DD" } , { ID: 12, Fet: "Cake", Name: "DD" }, { ID: 13, Fet: "Lemon", Name: "CC"}] ;
const grouped = arr.reduce((a,v) => {
    if( !(v.ID in a) ) a[v.ID] = [];
  a.Name = v.Name
  a[v.ID].push(v.Fet);
    return a;
},{});

var newArrayOfReducedObjects = Object.keys(grouped).map(key => {
    return { ID: key, Name: key, Fet: grouped[key] };
});

console.log(newArrayOfReducedObjects);
```

Comment: Seems like you just want `a[v.ID] = []` to be something like `a[v.ID] = {Name: v.Name, data: []}` and then `a[v.ID].data.push(v.Fet)` You could also put the `ID` on that object, and that'll be your eventual result.

Comment: ...like this: https://jsfiddle.net/zs8xadht/1/ ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use generic group by function which you can use with various keys for an array of objects.

```
var customGroupBy = function(xs, key) {
    return xs.reduce(function(rv, x) {
      (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x);
      return rv;
    }, {});
};
```

Then you can call this function for any key:

```
customGroupBy (arr,"ID")
customGroupBy (arr,"Name")
```

The last call above will result in (JSONified)

```
"{"DD":[{"ID":12,"Fet":"Donuts","Name":"DD"},{"ID":12,"Fet":"Cake","Name":"DD"}],"CC":[{"ID":13,"Fet":"Lemon","Name":"CC"}]}"
```